# how to limit, characters between a range using regular expression

Tags: regex

As far as I know `{}` curly braces are used to limit characters in regular expression like `{3,12}`, would match character length between 3 to 12.

I am trying to validate username that might contain a period `.` or `_` either one, but not both, doesn't matter placement. For this below regex is working very well.

```
(^[a-z0-9]+$)|(^[a-z0-9]*[\.\_][a-z0-9]*$)
```

But I also need to limit the string length between 3 to 12, I had tried to put `{3,12}` in regex, but that doesn't work.

```
((^[a-z0-9]+$)|(^[a-z0-9]*[\.\_][a-z0-9]*$)){3,12}
```

See Example: https://regex101.com/r/kN3aO1/1

Comment: A lot going on with the selected expression `^(?=.{3,12}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._][a-z0-9]+)?$` aside from the lookahead to valdate length, do you see the other subtle differences from your original regex ?

Comment: I had used `|`  to differentiate string with non period or underscore and vice versa different side, how ever I think hwnd's expression is better than mines as he didn't used or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `hwnd` suggested, a simpler solution would be:

```
^(?=.{3,12}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._][a-z0-9]+)?$
```

---

Old solution, which is rather complex and convoluted,is left here for reference, but use the one above instead.

```
^(?!(?:.{13,}|.{1,2})$)(?:([a-z0-9]+)|([a-z0-9]*[\.\_][a-z0-9]*))$
```

You can add a lookahead for this.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aG0sF5/8)

Comment: I would probably do `^(?=.{3,12}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._][a-z0-9]+)?$` instead.

Comment: could you please make me understand hwnd's regex, how that works, I mean explain it a bit - Thanks

Comment: @Developer my regex uses `negative lookahead` to make sure the string size is not greater than `13` or `1` or `2`.His regex uses `positive lookahead` to make sure string size  is between `3` to `12`.As `$` is there after `.{3,12}` the string should end there.The regex will pass only when `lookahead` passes

Comment: Please remove the first solution altogether, since it is quite a convoluted solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in three steps.

1. Check to see if the string has any '/' in it.
2. Check to see if the string has any '_' in it.
3. Check to see if string length is between 3 and 12.

In *Perl*:

```
if ( ( ( $name =~ /_/ ) && ( $name =~ /\./ ) ) ||
     ( length($name) < 3 ) ||
     ( length($name) > 12 ) )
{
    # Handle invalid username
}
```

If you want to make sure that the username contains *only one* dot or underscore, you may count them. Again, in Perl:

```
my $dcnt = $name =~ tr /././;
my $ucnt = $name =~ tr /_/_/;

if ( ( $dcnt > 0 && $ucnt > 0 ) ||
     ( $dcnt > 1 )         ||
     ( $ucnt > 1 )         ||
     ( length($name) < 3 ) ||
     ( length($name) > 12 ) )
{
    # Handle invalid username
}
```

Why not one monster regular expression that does everything at once? Well, for the sake of maintainability. If you or a colleague looks at this code in a year's time, when requirements have changed, this approach will make it easier to update the code.

Notice also that `{3,12}` says nothing about lengths. It allows the previous pattern to match three to twelve times.